# dispatch_async() block didn't finish before UITableViewDataSource methods

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

There is a `UITableView` which its cells will be filled by data got with HTTP post request. But `UITableView` functions executed before the data comes. When the application starts, all three `tableView` methods executed and then application throws a runtime error. I guess it's because in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `messageList` is still empty.

Here is the code:

```
class messageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var authData : NSDictionary = [:]
    var funcLib = functionLibrary()
    var messagesList : NSArray = []
    var messageCount: Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        var authCode = self.authData["auth"] as! String
        var userID = self.authData["user_id"] as! String
        var messageRequsetBodyData: AnyObject = ["op":"users","op2":"getThisWeekMessages","id":"\(userID)","id2":"","id3":"","authCode":"\(authCode)"] as AnyObject

        funcLib.HTTPPostRequest("http://asdasd.asdasdasd.com/services/index.php", bodyData: messageRequsetBodyData){data in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                if let data = data{

                    var messaggesListDic = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
                    println("------MESSAGGES---------")

                    self.messageCount = messaggesListDic["count"] as! Int
                    //self.messages = messaggesListDic["messages"] as! NSDictionary
                    self.messagesList = messaggesListDic["messages"] as! NSArray
                    println("\(self.messagesList)")
                    self.messageTableView.reloadData()
                }

            }

        }

        self.messageTableView.delegate = self
        self.messageTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func dismissMessageVC(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        println("asdasd")
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        println("asdasd")
        println("\(self.messageCount)")
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        println("bdbsdbsdb")
        var cell = self.messageTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell!.textLabel!.text = self.messagesList[0]["content"] as? String
        return cell!
    }
```

Runtime error description:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

I tried assign the cell label with using `cell.textLabel?.text = "asdasd"` command and it works. So I think there is no problem with outlets or methods.

How can I assign the data to `messageList` before `cellForRowAtIndexPath` executed with using different way?

Comment: You can do an if let on the string from the array and if can exist then assign the label to it.

Comment: But it wont exist anyway.

Comment: It will when you reload the table data from the closure

Comment: It's also possible that you don't have an internet connection meaning self.messageList will _never_ get populated. You need to fill self.messageList with empty content while you wait for the server to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return constant value for number of rows even if your message count is zero. Better to return message count.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    println("asdasd")
    println("\(self.messageCount)")
    return self.messageCount;
}
```

Comment: It worked with `return self.messageList.count.But there is lag. Is this because of `dispacth_async`? Lastly, Cells are empty first, then they are fills with data. Can you suggest some way to fix for it?

Comment: Cells are empty first time because you don't have any data. As for the lag I can't tell you where is a problem. Better to use Instruments for performance analysing. Maybe your JSON is too big and since you do deserialization on main thread you have lag, maybe something else.

Comment: yeah it should be lag. data is not big at all. but my internet connection is too slow right now. Thanks anyway:)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you have a table view that needs to make an asynchronous call to retrieve the data, you should expect the table view data source methods to be called before the asynchronous request is done. But, when the asynchronous request is done, when you simply call `tableView.reloadData()`, the table view data sources methods will be called a second time. This is a very common pattern.

The issue here, though, is that this code is not gracefully handling the situation that there is no data to display when the table view data sources methods are called the first time. If `numberOfRowsForSection` returned `0` until data was retrieved (as described by the others, notably by returning `messagesList.count()`, as suggested by John and Yedidya, rather than returning a fixed number), all would be good.

Comment: thanks for the information, i will keep that in my mind.

Comment: oh, you caught me while I was doing that:)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `numberOfRows` function return value with `messagesList.count`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but there is some issues still. Please look the first answer's comment.